# Insert statement with a conditional target column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to store sensor data recorded to the appropriate target column, depending on what the latest settings are in the settings table (represented as @Unit in the code). The code I have so far gives me a syntax error at line 19 near 'Time', which I am not sure as to why. Any ideas?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StoreTemp

@Temperature float,
@Seconds int,
@SessionId int,
@DatasetId int

AS

DECLARE

@Unit varchar(20),
@TempCol varchar(20)

SELECT @Unit = RecordingUnit from ReadLastUnit

SELECT @TempCol = (case @Unit when 'Celsius' then 'Temperature_C' else 'Temperature_F' END)

INSERT INTO DATASET (@TempCol, Time)

VALUES (@Temperature, GETDATE())

GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a variable to specify a column name in an insert statement. The column name must be static.

You could use dynamic SQL, however in this case you can just conditionally insert a value into the correct column using a case expression as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StoreTemp
(
  @Temperature float
  , @Seconds int
  , @SessionId int
  , @DatasetId int
)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @Unit varchar(20), @TempCol varchar(20);

  SELECT @Unit = RecordingUnit from ReadLastUnit;

  --SELECT @TempCol = (case @Unit when 'Celsius' then 'Temperature_C' else 'Temperature_F' END);

  INSERT INTO DATASET (Temperature_C, Temperature_F, [Time])
    SELECT
      CASE WHEN @Unit = 'Celsius' THEN @Temperature ELSE NULL END
      , CASE WHEN @Unit != 'Celsius' THEN @Temperature ELSE NULL END
      , GETDATE();
END
GO
```

For better performance and a neater query, you could even simplify the `insert` to do it all e.g.

```
INSERT INTO DATASET (Temperature_C, Temperature_F, [Time])
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN RecordingUnit = 'Celsius' THEN @Temperature ELSE NULL END
    , CASE WHEN RecordingUnit != 'Celsius' THEN @Temperature ELSE NULL END
    , GETDATE()
  from ReadLastUnit;
```

Thats assuming you can always guarantee a single row in `ReadLastUnit`.